# Overkill? On the proof of Monotone Class Theorem in Probability Theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation, monotone-class-theorem

I have studied the proof of [Monotone Class Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem) from John B. Walsh's [Knowing the Odds](http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-139). I feel that a part of the proof is an overkill. I'm attaching the proof below.

> The author has defined $\mathcal{G'}$ to be the smallest monotone class containing $\mathcal{F_0},$ but then defined the class $\mathcal{C_1}$ to show that $\mathcal{F_0} \subset \mathcal{C_1}=\mathcal{G'}$ and hence $\mathcal{G'}$ *contains* $\mathcal{F_0}$. If $\mathcal{G'}$ is *defined* to contain $\mathcal{F_0},$ why do we need to prove that again$?$

Any clarification on whether it is really an overkill or I'm just missing something would be much appreciated. Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role of the sets $\mathcal C_1$ and $\mathcal C_2$ is not to show that $\mathcal G'$ contains $\mathcal F_0$; that is immediate from the definition of $\mathcal G'$, as you have noted. Their role is to show that $\mathcal G'$ is closed under finite intersections, which is the relevant remark in the second sentence you highlight.

Comment: Thanks. So we need $\mathcal{C_1}=\mathcal{G'}$ to show that $\mathcal{C_2}$ actually contains $\mathcal{F_0}$. Otherwise we can't say that $\mathcal{C_2} \supset \mathcal{G'}$.